# File uploade with additional Data (Javascript, PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, file-upload, jquery-file-upload

I want to uploade a file and send additional data (an array) to the php script.

Here is the HTML and the Javascript Code:

```
<input type="file" name="fileinput" id="fileinput">
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnupload">upload</button>
<script>

$('#btnupload').click(function(){
 var formData = new FormData();
 formData.append("MacsToChangeImage", selectedMACs.toString()); //selectedMACs is the array which i want to send
 formData.append("userfile", $('#fileinput').files[0]);
 $.ajax({
  url: "ChangeImagesFunction.php",
  type:'POST',
  data: formData,
  processData: false,
  cententType: false,
  success: function(data)
  {
      alert('success' + data);
  },
  error:function(response){
    alert(JSON.stringify(response));
  }
 });
});

</script>
```

And here ist the PHP Code:

```
if(!empty($_FILES)) {
 $target_dir = "img/epd_uploads/";
 $temporaryFile = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
 $targetFile =  $target_dir . $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
 if(!move_uploaded_file($temporaryFile,$targetFile))  {
   echo "Error occurred while uploading the file to server!";
 }else{
    if (isset($_POST['MacsToChangeImage'])){
    //Name of the Uploaded File
    $ChangeImageToPHP = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
    //Get the Array
    $MacsToChangeImageStr = $_POST['MacsToChangeImage'];
    $MacsToChangeImagePHP = explode(",",$MacsToChangeImageStr);
    }
  }
}
```

I think the HTML and Javascript part is fine so far. But i am uncertain how to handle the PHP part. What am i doing worng/missing?

Are there other ways to achieve what im plannig to do?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please paste your code here directly, rather than using images

Comment: i changed it now